# SYMFONY 3 standalone or embed form

Tags: symfony

I have created a form that i use as  standalone or embed .
Is it possible to display fields only if  if the  form  is used alone ?

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

IF $this->parentFieldDescription  == TRUE  my form is in embed form